# string trim start

Tags: c#, string

this code delivers the correct result,

```
Locations[i] = Locations[i].TrimStart(@"..\Config\Locations".ToCharArray());
```

But not this

```
String loc = Properties.Settings.Default.pathTo + @"\Config\Locations";
Locations[i] = Locations[i].TrimStart(loc.ToCharArray());
```

doesn't work. I think `Properties.Settings.Default.pathTo` must be escaped, but I do not know how to do it.

Comment: What is a correct result and what you're receiving instead? **Always** provide as much information as needed to get into your problem.

Comment: corrrect result are the folders of the directory Locations and I get just an emty string if I use the second code

Comment: Properties.Settings.Default.pathTo  is C:\dir

Answer (score 1):

`TrimStart` removes *individual characters* from the start of a string, it does not remove a string.  In other words your example will remove all dots, slashes, `'C'`s, `'o'`s, `'n'`s, etc. from the start - they do not not necessarily have to be in the order of your source string.

I think you want something like this:

```
if(Locations[i].StartsWith(loc);
    Locations[i] = Locations[i].Substring(loc.Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you understand that `ToCharArray` means that those characters will be removed `in any order` (as long as there're no other chars in between)...

You may wanted to do something like this really (I may be wrong though)

```
    public static string StripStart(this string text, string value, bool ignoreCase = false)
    {
        // if(text.EndsWith...
        if (text.StartsWith(value, ignoreCase, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            return text.Substring(value.Length);
        return text;
    }
```

This is very simplistic but should work

hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

I think NSGaga is right,hope it help you

```
public static string StripStart(this string text, string value, bool ignoreCase = false)
{
    if (text.StartsWith(value, ignoreCase, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        return text.Substring(value.Length);
    return text;
}
```

Comment: If you agree with an answe,r add a comment to that answer rather that reposting the answer verbatim.